# NetSuite saved search get the timestamp with the time offset

Tags: expression, netsuite, saved-searches

I need the date (record's {datecreated}) from saved search to have the timezone offset(eg.-0500).
So until now I found the date pattern that may be used is this one: `YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFTZH:TZM`
So I tested this `TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ({datecreated}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')` but the returned hours are not correct (eg. 2023-03-31T00:00:00-04:00). So I tried `TO_CHAR({datecreated}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM')` but this returns `ERROR: Invalid Expression`. I found that I can get the right time only this way `TO_CHAR({datecreated}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS')` but offset isn't listed.
So my question: has NetSuite a native way to get the correct time with time zone offset or only way is to concatenate the date from different methods? thx

Comment: "I tested this TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ({datecreated}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SSTZH:TZM') but the returned hours are not correct (eg. 2023-03-31T00:00:00-04:00)" - what result are you expecting?  Could it be explained by the time difference between where you are and where the NetSuite server is located (PDT)?

Comment: The issue is that `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` returns always `00:00:00` as time but I expect eg. 12:23:00, 14:34:00, etc
The date results in NS are based on user preferences. In my case it's "EDT" so now it's `-04:00`. BUT in NS database the system saves the exacte time of event. You can test this TO_CHAR({datecreated}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') and change your time zone from Home>Set Preferences to see the hours value changed by zone. I know in scripts the `new Date().toString()` returns PDT... even if the server is near New York ;)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error I found that NetSuite have `SESSIONTIMEZONE` variable and it also have the `TZ_OFFSET` method. So I concatenated the data from 2 methods to have an "usable" timestamp.

`TO_CHAR({datecreated}, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS') || TZ_OFFSET(SESSIONTIMEZONE)`
It will return the exacte date & time with time zone offset. eg.`2023-03-31T13:02:07-04:00`.

PS. `SESSIONTIMEZONE` returned values are based on the user preferences.